# validation system it works for some input and it doesn't work for others uses jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

i tried to apply validation system uses jQuery i include bootstrap CDN and jQuery and jQuery validation. while input name works fine and input title doesn't work.

hi, i tried to apply validation system uses jQuery i include bootstrap CDN and jQuery and jQuery validation. while input name works fine and input title doesn't work.

hi, i tried to apply validation system uses jQuery i include bootstrap CDN and jQuery and jQuery validation. while input name works fine and input title doesn't work.

```js
   
 $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
          });
          $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {

              title: {
                required: true,
                minlength:2,
                maxlength:5,
              },
              name: {
                required: true,
                minlength:2,
                maxlength:5,
              },

            }
          });
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>rules</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.2/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form id="myform">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
     <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
        <option>select</option>
        <option value="1">title</option>
        <option value="2">name</option>
     </select>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>title <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="titre" id="title" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>name <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-theme" type="submit"  >cherche</button>
    </form>
 </div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct the name of the title field.

Comment: @RohitUtekar yes exactly thx its solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo here: `<input type="text" name="titre" id="title" class="form-control"/>`

titre should be title